# Open my application when double click on a folder using c/c++

Tags: c, windows

I want to open my application when i double click on a folder. I want to associate a folder with my application so that before the folder is opened, i can perform some operation and then based on the result of the operation i can decide if to open the folder or not.

Is there a way to redirect the open function of the folder to my application?

I am using Windows 7

Can you help?

Comment: You need to specify the OS & desktop environment before anyone can even begin to answer this question.

Comment: Also, which language are you programming in? You named two distinct languages.

Comment: I am using windows and i am programming in C

Comment: just in standalone explorer, or in all shell viewers, e.g. file dialogs

Comment: Its a custom dialog that i want to open when double click on the folder

Comment: No I mean do you only want this to happen when the shell is being hosted by Explorer. Shell can be hosted in lots of other places too. Most commonly in file dialogs. Anyway, what you are describing sounds like a pretty bad idea. What happens is the user navigates to the folder some other way? Double clicking is not the only form of UI.

Comment: What i trying to do is that when i open a folder, just before opening it in explorer, it prompts the user to enter a password in a dialog box. If the correct password is entered then the folder will open else not.

Comment: Well, now we are getting somewhere. That's what you need to be stating in the question. Now, why are you concentrating on Explorer? Is it OK for the files to be opened without a password using some other file viewer? And what about from the command line. Again, do you mind if the password can be skipped from the command line.

Comment: No the password cannot be skipped. Thats the purpose of the application. It's not files that i want to open, it's only directories/folders.

Answer (score 0):

Very very bad idea. Write rather driver with using ZwQueryInformationFile and similar functions for purpose of this.
Or write shell namespace extension and in your IShellFolder::EnumObjects implementation may show your 'super' password dialog. :-)
More: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775066(v=vs.85).aspx